# Doctrine oridinal number with mysql (Error: Expected Literal, got '@')

Tags: mysql, doctrine, row-number

I need to have an oridinal number from mysql database. I found how emulate of row_num in mysql like this:

```
    SET @row=0;
    SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS no, id,  name FROM `attribute` ORDER BY id
     ) t WHERE name LIKE "%Jo%"
```

I begin code with:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->exec("SET @counter = 0");
```

and I tried:

```
        $this->result = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select('a')
            ->where($expr->in('att.ordinal_number', $this->createQueryBuilder('att')->
                    select('(@counter:=@counter+1) AS ordinal_number')->
                    from(\App\Entity\Attribute::class, 'att')->
                    orderBy('att.id')->getDQL()))
```

and I tried:

```
        $this->result = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select('a')
            ->addSelect('(SELECT (@counter:=@counter+1) AS oridinal_number, id, '
                    .' name FROM App:Entity:Atrribute ORDER BY id)')
```

Above give me:

> Error: Expected Literal, got '@'

Anybody know how to emulate row_number in doctrine with mysql?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no direct way to incorporate these DB variables in DQL or query builder, you will need to execute [**Native SQL**](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql) and then use [`ResultSetMapping`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/native-sql.html#examples) class to map the result of query to your entity

SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS no, 
            id,
            name
    FROM `attribute` ,(SELECT @row:=0) t
    ORDER BY id
) t WHERE name LIKE "%Jo%"
```

Resultset Mapping

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('Attribute', 'a');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'name', 'name');
$rsm->addScalarResult('no', 'no');

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('SELECT * 
                                        FROM (
                                            SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS no, 
                                                    id,
                                                    name
                                            FROM attribute ,(SELECT @row:=0) t
                                            ORDER BY id
                                        ) t WHERE name LIKE ?',$rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, '%Jo%');
$users = $query->getResult();
```